# Cannot Send Message to Other ViewController

Tags: objective-c, methods, call

I was messing around in Xcode creating... something... when I needed to send a message to the `MainViewController.m` from the `FlipsideViewController.m`. Except, when I do, the ViewController I am sending the message from does not detect the method as existing, despite the fact that I put the method in `MainViewController.h`. This is the method:

```
- (void)setAutosave:(BOOL)boolee {
    _autosave = boolee;
}
```

I have imported the MainViewController into the FlipsideViewController, but as I call it (`[NSMainViewController setAutosave:_autosave];`), it simply throws an error:

`No known class method for selector 'setAutosave:'`

I am doing this because `FlipsideViewController` has a segmented control in it, which tells `autosave` to be on or off, but it needs to send it's value to the other ViewController.

I really am stumped, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainViewController` is a class, you can't access instance method from a class.

You can add a property to FlipsideViewController, for example:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainViewController;
```

Assign your MainViewController instance to mainViewController (how to assign depends on the relationship between your two view controllers), then you can invoke that method by `[self.mainViewController setAutosave:_autosave];`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Could you please explain how I could send the autosave variable from FlipsideViewController to MainViewController?

Comment: Awesome. It looks like it should work, but Xcode attempts to correct it to MainViewController again instead of mainViewController. But, when it does, it is the same error...

Comment: Sorry, self.mainViewController

Comment: Wow it is fixed! Thanks!