# Modifying string content in NSTextView works under viewDidLoad method, but not under myMethod

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to update the contents of an NSTextView that is connected to myViewController as a referencing outlet to the Files Owner which is the subclass myViewController.

When I use an IBAction from a button, or use the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller, I can update the text fine.  However, when I try run the method from another class (referred to in this example as `anotherViewController`), it runs the method, but the textview does not change.

**myViewController.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "anotherViewController.h"


@interface myViewController : NSViewController { }
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *outText;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *updateMeButton;

- (void)updateTextView:(NSString *)argText;
- (void)updateTextViewWithoutArg;

@end
```

**myViewController.m:**

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@interface myViewController ()
@end

@implementation myViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.outText.string = @"I work successfully";
}   

- (IBAction)updateMeButton:(id)sender {
    self.outText.string = @"I am updated text!  I also work!";
}

- (void)updateTextView:(NSString *)argText {
    self.outText.string = @"I don't make it to the NSTextView :(";
    NSLog(@"Should have updated text view");
}

- (void)updateTextViewWithoutArg {
    self.outText.string = @"I don't make it to the NSTextView :(";
    NSLog(@"Should have updated text view");
}

@end
```

In **anotherViewController.m** , which has all the relevant imports, I call this:

```
myViewController *viewtask = [[myViewController alloc] init];
[viewtask updateTextViewWithoutArg];
```

Nothing happens.  The method runs and logs that it should have updated, but no text updates.  I have tried many different approaches, including textstorage and scrollrange methods, they all work the already working sections, but make no difference in the sections not working.

I've also tried just for fun:

```
myViewController *viewtask;
[viewtask updateTextViewWithoutArg];
```

- Also using the instance variable `_outText`
- Also using `[self.outText setString:@"string"];`
- Also using `[_outText setString:@"string"];`

Again, they work but only in the already working sections.

This should be simple but isn't logical to me.  In swift all I need to do is
 `self.outText.string = "I update whenever I'm called!"`

Comment: You have to send `updateTextViewWithoutArg` to the existing view controller. `[[myViewController alloc] init]` creates a new view controller.

Comment: [Need to call methods in other viewControllers from another viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130334/need-to-call-methods-in-other-viewcontrollers-from-another-viewcontroller) and [Cannot Send Message to Other ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058039/cannot-send-message-to-other-viewcontroller).

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views you create in Interface Builder are lazily created, so if you access them before `viewDidLoad` is called they are `nil`.

If your case, calling

```
 myViewController *viewtask = [[myViewController alloc] init];
```

does not cause the views to be created so when you call

```
[viewtask updateTextViewWithoutArg];
```

`self.outText` is `nil`.

You can see that this is what is happening by updating your code as below:

```
- (void)updateTextView:(NSString *)argText {
    NSAssert(self.outText != nil, @"self.outText must not be nil");
    self.outText.string = @"I don't make it to the NSTextView :(";
    NSLog(@"Should have updated text view");
}
```

you should see the assert fire.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In my case the view (which is a debug output window) is first being created (by a "show" segue), **then** I am going to update that view, by clicking a button in the *other* view.  Do you know how I can send a message to the view that was already created ?

Comment: It's a bit hard to give a specific answer without being able to see all the code involved, but there are two main ways: (1) when debug view controller is created you can get a pointer to it in `prepareForSegue` using `[segue destinationViewController]` for a more loosely coupled solution (2) use `NSNotificationCenter`. Since you mention you may want to access it from many view controllers (2) may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have found a solution by making `myViewController` a singleton class and using `sharedInstance`.  For this particlar app, `myViewController` is a debug output window and will never need to be placed in another view.

I won't accept this answer yet, as it's not the best one I'm sure.  **There may still be a proper solution presented** that allows finding the applicable `myViewController` instance, and modifying the `outText` property attached to it.  Using this singleton makes subclassing tedious as I would have to make a new class for every instance if I wanted to be able to address say 10 View Controllers.

Anyway - the way I've been able to satisfy my simple requirement:

**myViewController.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "anotherViewController.h"


@interface myViewController : NSViewController { }
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *outText;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *updateMeButton;

- (void)updateTextView:(NSString *)argText;
- (void)updateTextViewWithoutArg;

+ (id)sharedInstance;
@end
```

**myViewController.m:**

```
#import "myViewController.h"

@interface myViewController ()
@end

@implementation myViewController

static myViewController *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (myViewController *)sharedInstance {
    static myViewController *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[myViewController alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sharedInstance = self;  
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    sharedInstance = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.outText.string = @"I work successfully";
}   

- (IBAction)updateMeButton:(id)sender {
    sharedInstance.outText.string = @"Button Pressed";
}

- (void)updateTextView:(NSString *)argText {
    sharedInstance.outText.string = argText;
}

- (void)updateTextViewWithoutArg {
    sharedInstance.outText.string = @"I make it to the TextView now";
}

@end
```

Now when I use this code from within **anotherViewController.m** it updates the right instance:

```
[myViewController.sharedInstance updateTextView:@"Updating with this string"];
```